# How to Increase Value in Firebase by Pressing Button Continuously in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to using Android Studio, and now I want to create some buttons which can increase the value of my Firebase Realtime Database whenever I click the button. However, I want to make the value keep increasing whenever I long click the button, and the value returns to zero when I release the button. I have tried to code and here's my `MainActivity` code :

```
package com.example.try6;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.try6.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private DatabaseReference database;
    private int number = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        initializeComponents();

    }

    private void initializeComponents() {
        Button[] buttons = {
                binding.btnGasUp, binding.btnGasDown,
                binding.btnYawRight, binding.btnYawLeft,
                binding.btnRollRight, binding.btnRollLeft,
                binding.btnPitchFront, binding.btnPitchBack,
        };
        for (Button button : buttons) {
            button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (button == binding.btnGasUp) {
                    setOnClick(1, "Gas");
                } else if (button == binding.btnGasDown) {
                    setOnClick(-1, "Gas");
                } else if (button == binding.btnYawRight) {
                    setOnClick(1, "Yaw");
                } else if (button == binding.btnYawLeft) {
                    setOnClick(-1, "Yaw");
                } else if (button == binding.btnRollRight) {
                    setOnClick(1, "Roll");
                } else if (button == binding.btnRollLeft) {
                    setOnClick(-1, "Roll");
                } else if (button == binding.btnPitchFront) {
                    setOnClick(1, "Pitch");
                } else if (button == binding.btnPitchBack) {
                    setOnClick(-1, "Pitch");
                }
            });
            button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    if (button == binding.btnGasUp) {
                        setOnLongClick(number++, "Gas");
                    } else if (button == binding.btnGasDown) {
                        setOnLongClick(number--,"Gas");
                    } else if (button == binding.btnYawRight) {
                        setOnLongClick(number++,"Yaw");
                    } else if (button == binding.btnYawLeft) {
                        setOnLongClick(number--,"Yaw");
                    } else if (button == binding.btnRollRight) {
                        setOnLongClick(number++,"Roll");
                    } else if (button == binding.btnRollLeft) {
                        setOnLongClick(number--,"Roll");
                    } else if (button == binding.btnPitchFront) {
                        setOnLongClick(number++, "Pitch");
                    } else if (button == binding.btnPitchBack) {
                        setOnLongClick(number--,"Pitch");
                    }
                    number = 0;
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setOnClick(int increment, String path) {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Control");
        database.child(path).setValue(ServerValue.increment(increment)).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            CharSequence text = "The value was failed to add";
            int toast = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, toast).show();
        });
    }
    private void setOnLongClick(int increment, String path){
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Control");
        database.child(path).setValue(ServerValue.increment(increment)).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            CharSequence text = "The value was failed to add";
            int toast = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, toast).show();
        });
    }

}
```

And this is the result :
[The Result on Firebase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPCr1.png)

It works for `setOnClickListener()` event even though the value did not return to zero (The value increase whenever i click the button only) but the `setOnLongClickListener()` event did not work at all.
Any suggestions what should i do? Or am i do some mistakes?
Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're looking for a long click or for a continuously click?

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry if it's confusing. What I mean is that pressing the button increments the value in my Firebase Realtime Database continuously until I release the button. After that it goes back to zero once I release the button.

Comment: What is the rate of incrementation during the pressing the button?

Comment: @AlexMamo For now I want the value to keep increasing by 1 as long as I hold down the button. But maybe I'll change it later. So it's better if the number can be changed as i like

Comment: Let's say you keep the button pressed for 1 minute, how many times would you like to increment the value?

Comment: @AlexMamo Hmm, I think the value keeps increasing every 500 milliseconds as long as I hold down the button.

Comment: @AlexMamo I've tried the code answered by @Vibrant below and it can keep increasing by 1 as long as I hold down the button. But the value doesn't go back to zero when I release the button and it continues until I stop the app. You can check my modified code [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16NtQcB162YmVuI7IQvJL8qs2gyJvjoEk?usp=sharing) at `Try6\app\src\main\java\com\example\try6`. Any idea?

Comment: Does an answer in Kotlin help? Or do you need Java?

Comment: @AlexMamo Due to my little understanding of kotlin so I prefer java but if you can give me an idea through kotlin you can continue

Answer (score 2):

Design your layout:

Open your layout XML file (e.g., activity_main.xml) and add a button element. You can customize its appearance as desired.
Example XML for the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/increaseButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Increase"
    />
```

Retrieve a reference to your Firebase Realtime Database:

In your activity or fragment, declare a variable for the Firebase Realtime Database reference.
Example code:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
```

Initialize the Firebase Realtime Database reference:

Inside your activity's onCreate() method or fragment's onViewCreated() method, initialize the database reference.
Example code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Set click and long-click listeners for the button:

In your activity or fragment, find the button by its ID and set both a click listener and a long-click listener on it.
Example code:

```
Button increaseButton = findViewById(R.id.increaseButton);

increaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        increaseValue();
    }
});

increaseButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        startIncreasingValue();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Implement the methods for increasing the value:

Create two methods, increaseValue() and startIncreasingValue(), in your activity or fragment to handle the logic of increasing the value and updating it in Firebase.
Example code:

```
private int value = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable increaseRunnable;

private void increaseValue() {
    value++;
    mDatabase.child("your_node_path").setValue(value);
}

private void startIncreasingValue() {
    increaseRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            increaseValue();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100); // Increase every 100 milliseconds
        }
    };
    handler.post(increaseRunnable);
}
```

Stop increasing the value when the button is released:

Override the onTouchEvent() method in your activity or fragment and stop the increasing mechanism when the button is released.
Example code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        stopIncreasingValue();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private void stopIncreasingValue() {
    if (increaseRunnable != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(increaseRunnable);
        increaseRunnable = null;
    }
    value = 0;
    mDatabase.child("your_node_path").setValue(value);
}
```

Remember to replace "your_node_path" with the actual path to your desired node in the Firebase Realtime Database.

These steps will allow you to create a button in your Android app that increases the value in your Firebase Realtime Database when clicked and keeps increasing when long-pressed. The value will reset to zero when the button is released.

Please let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: what if i want to decrease the value to minus? should i create a new method? or is there another way to do it?

Comment: just use this : ```ServerValue.increment(-1)``` it will keep decreasing the value. Also : if you like my previous answer then please upvote it

Comment: Sorry, i've tried your code but the value just keep increasing when i hold down the button without returning to zero when i release the button, so it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: can you share your modified code

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16NtQcB162YmVuI7IQvJL8qs2gyJvjoEk?usp=sharing) you can find it at `Try6\app\src\main\java\com\example\try6`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have layout that contains a button and looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/longPressButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Long Press Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To achieve a functionality in which you increment a value every 500 milliseconds while the button is pressed and when the button is released, to set the value to zero, then please define inside your activity five global variables:

```
private Button longPressButton;
private Handler toastHandler;
private Runnable toastRunnable;
private boolean isButtonPressed;
private DatabaseReference valueRef;
```

And inside `onCreate()`, add the following lines of code:

```
longPressButton = findViewById(R.id.longPressButton);
toastHandler = new Handler();
isButtonPressed = false;
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
valueRef = db.child("value");

longPressButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                isButtonPressed = true;
                incrementRepeatedly();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                isButtonPressed = false;
                setValueToZero();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

And here are the corresponding methods:

```
private void incrementRepeatedly() {
    toastRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isButtonPressed) {
                valueRef.setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));
                toastHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        }
    };
    toastHandler.postDelayed(toastRunnable, 500);
}

private void setValueToZero() {
    valueRef.setValue(0);

}
```

To make it work in your project, you have to set your own references in the database.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: Wow it works, thanks. But there's a problem. When the app is launched for the first time, if I just click the button not for a long time, the app will force kill. What should i do to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the app will force kill"? Are you getting an error? What does the error message says?

Comment: Sorry, i mean the app will forced to close when i try to click the button only not for a long time and i got this : `  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference `

Comment: Although i've handled this by adding toggle button and i put your code in a method so the code will work when i click the toggle button. But, any idea?

Comment: The code I have provided you works either with a long click or a simple click. I personally tried it and I get no error. The error says that you call `.setValue` on an object which is null. So I recommend you then use something like `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("value").setValue(ServerValue.increment(1));` Does it work this way?

Comment: Oh Thank you, i know my mistake now. I put the `valueRef = db.child("value");` in `if(isButtonPressed)` condition because i want to create multiple buttons with similar functionality that makes `.setValue` gets a null object reference. So i decided to put it into `incrementRepeatedly()` method and it works.

Comment: Good to hear that it works now :) So can I help you with other information?

Comment: I think that's enough, thank you. And sorry i can't upvote your answer bcs i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote.

Comment: Is there everything alright?